# Robotframework android screen detection after pop-up

Tags: python, appium, robotframework

After closing a pop-up window, my code somehow does not recognize changed screen.
***Short description:*** I press button, pop-up shows up that my "Camera is offline", I press OK, and then I am waiting until page has "Add new camera" written on here. In my screen it shows up, when I try to debug it also shows that this keyword is in page, but my test fails.

I tried to change elements which to wait till it shows.
I tried to use sleep function.
I have another places that the code does not work - when I close pop-up window, my code does not recognize new page.

```
Click Element    com.yummiapps.eldes:id/a_add_camera_b_add    #add button to get a pop-up window
Wait Until Page Contains    Camera is offline and cannot be added  #waiting till pop-up shows
Click Element    com.yummiapps.eldes:id/d_e_b_ok  #clicking on button from pop-uo
Wait Until Page Contains    Add new camera   #afte closing pop-up this segment always fails
```

Last code line should recognize that page is refreshed and it contains string "Add new camera"

[pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hlbq.png)
[after closing pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TaEm.png)

Comment: When I am using Appium Inspector and after pressing the button, the screen freezes and that could be the case why my Code does not work. But I am still not sure how does this screen freezes and what could be the causes.
Picture: http://prntscr.com/opdhzw